# APEX Map <String,Custom Object> GetKey Issues on trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, map

I am building a trigger to update ownership of Leads however while creating my map using String, Custom Object for somereason that I am unsure of is not finding the Key. When using the debuger logs I actually hard coded the Key when using Get. I am a bit stumped.

```
Trigger SalesAssignments on Lead (After insert, After Update) {
 List<Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c> lstSalesforceSalesAssignments = new List<Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c>();
 Set<ID> lstIdSalesforceSalesAssignments = new Set<ID>();

 For (Lead soLead : Trigger.New){

   If (Trigger.isInsert){
          If (soLead.Country != Null){

              //Create a Map of Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c
              Map<String, Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c> mapSalesforceSalesAssignments = new Map<String, Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c>
              ([Select Country__c, ID, User__c, City__c, County__c, State_Province__c, Zip_Code__c
                    From Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c
                        Where Country__c =: 'Aland Islands']);

              //If Country Does not Equal the USA then 
          If (soLead.Country != 'United States'){
               If(mapSalesforceSalesAssignments.containsKey(soLead.Country) ){ 

                   id U = mapSalesforceSalesAssignments.get('Aland Islands').User__c;

               }
           }     
         }
      }
  }
}
```

I can see that the Map is

> 07:30:38:163 USER_DEBUG [28]|DEBUG|DEBUG: mapSalesforceSalesAssignments                  {a3I1F000000XGCJUA4=Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c:{Country__c=Aland Islands, Id=a3I1F000000XGCJUA4, User__c=005U0000000Z09cIAC, Zip_Code__c=33333}}

so Lead.Country if not hard coded is

> 07:30:38:163 USER_DEBUG [29]|DEBUG|DEBUG: soLead.Country                  Aland Islands

Comment: Can you show us a failing example? Perhaps worth noting too that unlike most other places in Apex, Map `get()` is case-sensitive - odds are this is a data issue.

Comment: That is what I thought as well which is why I hard coded the data so that I knew it was exact match. If I take out the if statement and just use Get I get an error of Attempted to de-reference a null because it cant find it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c> mapSalesforceSalesAssignments = new Map<String, Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c>
          ([Select Country__c, ID, User__c, City__c, County__c, State_Province__c, Zip_Code__c
                From Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c
                    Where Country__c =: 'Aland Islands']);
```

The above code will create a `Map<Id, Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c>` and not any other field. Fore more reference on map constructors, refer to this - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm

In order to populate the map as per your need, you need to manually traverse the query results and form the map.

Also I'd suggest you to please follow query indentation and capitalization as that would improve readability.

Comment: Are you saying that I litterally need touse the Put statement????  Account a = new Account(
                   Name='Acme', 
                   BillingCity='New York');
                
                Map<String, Account> map1 = new Map<String, Account> {};
                map1.put('Test Test', a);
                
          //map1.get('Test Test').Name;
              
               system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG: map1.get(Test Test).User__c;                  ' + map1.get('Test Test').Name);

Comment: Yes, but in your above case, instead of using Account a = new Account().... you'll have to use the for loop to iterate on the records returned by the query.

Comment: Ugh..... That is such garbage. I see what you are saying but seriously. I wanted to create map so that I could get values easily because there could be a ton of records. I might as well use a list based on this.